# How to generate a Vanity domain in windows 10?

Tags: onion-services, windows

Basically what the title says. I cannot find a tool that does it for me for Windows 10 in 2021.

Comment: This question belongs on [tor.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get a specific .onion address for your hidden service?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29772/how-do-you-get-a-specific-onion-address-for-your-hidden-service)

Comment: @vidarlo no, as I cannot run it on my computer... do you have something that I can use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Tor names are hashes. In the past some services brute forced a series of hashes until they found one that was close. The new longer hashes are even more difficult to brute force. You can try, and you may get something acceptable, but there is no tool.

Comment: How can I try that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the hidden service names are derived from key pairs, so the **one and only** way to do so - is just a bruteforce, as it's done by a lot of software.